# Problem with getting SafeImageHtml in CustomItem.xsl of a CQWP

Tags: content-query-web-part, xslt, site-column, image

I have a CQWP with the Parameters:

> Title:{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247},Title,Text;|
>   Description:{691b9a4b-512e-4341-b3f1-68914130d5b2},ShortComment,Text;|
>   ImageUrl:{543bc2cf-1f30-488e-8f25-6fe3b689d9ac},PublishingRollupImage,Image;|
>   LinkUrl:|

and the following XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  exclude-result-prefixes="x d xsl msxsl cmswrt"
  xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp"
  xmlns:cmswrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v3/Publishing/runtime"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
  <xsl:param name="ItemsHaveStreams">
    <xsl:value-of select="'False'" />
  </xsl:param>
  <xsl:variable name="OnClickTargetAttribute" select="string('javascript:this.target=&quot;_blank&quot;')" />
  <xsl:variable name="ImageWidth" />
  <xsl:variable name="ImageHeight" />
  <xsl:template name="Default" match="*" mode="itemstyle">
    <xsl:variable name="SafeLinkUrl">
      <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetSafeLink">
        <xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="'LinkUrl'"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="SafeImageUrl">
      <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetSafeStaticUrl">
        <xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="'ImageUrl'"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="DisplayTitle">
      <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetTitle">
        <xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="'Title'"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>

     <xsl:variable name="SafeImageHtml">
        <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetColumnDataForUnescapedOutput">
           <xsl:with-param name="Name" select="'PublishingRollupImage'" /> 
           <xsl:with-param name="MustBeOfType" select="'Image'" />
           <xsl:with-param name="PublishingPageImage" select="'Image'" /> 
         </xsl:call-template>
       </xsl:variable>

 HTMLSHOULDBEGINAFTERTHIS
 <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$SafeImageHtml" />
 HTMLSHOULDSTOPAFTERTHIS

  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As you can see, i tried getting SafeImageHtml but  does not output anything. What could be the reason for that? (There are 3 Items in the list which is searched for, and all of them have their columns filled)

I tried something like this before:

```
<a href="{$SafeLinkUrl}">
<img src="{$SafeImageUrl}" title="{@ImageUrlAltText}"/>
</a>
```

But the Problem with that is that the link is formated on the RichText Field - so SafeLinkUrl gives me something like `http://mysp/sites/Lists/Testlist/1_.000` here.

Comment: In the variable `SafeImageUrl` - Why `<xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="'ImageUrl'"/>` and not `<xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="'PublishingRollupImage'"/>`?